# inherit all getter/setter methods of a java obj

Tags: java

I have a class A with a number of setter/getter methods, and want to implement a class B which "extends A" and provides other functionality.

I cannot modify class A, and it doesn't have a clone or constructor method that that takes a class A obj as a parameter. So basically I implement class B such that

- it has a constructor that takes a class A obj as a parameter and keeps a copy of this obj
- when we call setter/getter methods on B, it delegates to the class A obj
- other functionality...

Class A has many setter/getter methods and I feel this implementation is not clean but not sure how to fix this. Usually I can make B extend A, but in this case I have to be able to take a class A obj as a parameter for the constructor.

I'm sorry if the question is not clear enough, please let me know if you need more clarifications. Thanks.

Example:

```
public class A {
    private int x;
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public int getX() { return this.x; }
}

public class B {
    private A a;
    public B(A a) { this.a = a; }
    public void setX(int x) { a.setX(x); }
    public int getX() { return a.getX(); }
    public void foo() { ... };
    public void bar() { ... };
}
```

Basically A has a lots of properties X/Y/Z... and has many setters/getters. If I do this then B have many dummy setters/getters which simply delegate to the same call on a. Is there a cleaner way to implement this?

Comment: So, what code did you write ? You know SO users won't do your assignment for you.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just make B extend A in this case

Comment: Because class A doesn't provide a constructor that take an obj A as a param, and I don't have access to A's source code.

Comment: `B` can have such constructor, there's no need that `A` has it.

Comment: There is no shortcut for this, unless you do something like `get("X")` and use reflection.

Comment: I think you don't understand some basic concepts of Object-oriented programming and/or Java syntax. You really don't need to modify A's code to declare a class B that extends it. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Bubletan: I hope there would be a better solution than using reflection :(

Comment: Just for clarification: you wish to have a method (or constructor) that copies (deep?) an instance of A, such that when you call such a method (or constructor), you are left with another instance of A that contains the same field values as the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to extend an object of class A to add functionality to it and this is creating this dilemma. You can't copy A easily with a copy constructor and so you're trying to use composition rather than inheritance, and then that's not working.

Three options:

- Do what you're doing - wrap the object of type A as something owned by B and delegate - it works and it's not too bad
- Subclass A with B and then use some sort of reflection based copy routine to copy all properties from the object of type A into the new object of type B - e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ copyProperties function
- Create a copy constructor in class B that does what you want

Example

```
public class A {
    private int x;
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public int getX() { return this.x; }
}

public class B {
    public B(A a) {
        // copy all A properties from the object that we're going to extend
        this.setX(a.getX());
    }

    .. other stuff
}
```

The problem you're describing is one of extending an object. Extending a class is straightforward - just subclass it, and you have the base implementation plus your new stuff. To extend an object with the above code:

```
A someA = new A();

// a is initialised as an A

B aWithExtraProperties = new B(someA);

// now you have a B which has the same values as the original A plus
// b's properties
// and as B subclasses A, you can use it in place of the original A
```

I've tried changing an object's type at runtime like this before and it doesn't feel nice. It may be better to consider why you're doing this at all and whether there are alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. My main concern with the 1st and 3rd solutions is that there are many property Xs in A, and there will be new properties introduced in A. It's hard to maintain and code looks very ugly. The 2nd solution would be the best.

Comment: I still wonder why this is really useful compared to other patterns. You appear to be trying to change an object's type at runtime. Google that phrase for more patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If class B extends class A, it will automatically inherit all its non-private non-static methods. In your code, the getter/setters in class A are declared public, so class B will inherit them.

However, for this to work, you will need to rewrite class B's signature as follows, abd remove pretty much all code you wrote in B's body :

```
public class B extends A {
    // here, put any functionalities that B provides in addition to those inherited from A
}
```

This way, you can access all the getter/setters through any reference of type A or B, like this :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setName("Bob");
    System.out.println(a.getName());

    B b = new B();
    b.setName("Joe");
    System.out.println(b.getName());

    // And even this, thanks to polymorphism :
    A ab = new B();
    ab.setName("Mike");
    System.out.println(ab.getName());
}
```

Comment: I need a constructor that takes an obj A as a param and I cannot modify class A.

Comment: So what ? I fail to see how not being able to modify class A would prevent any other class to declare a constructor accepting an instance of A as a parameter.